# Greensock GSAP: Translating CSS cubic-bezier to GSAP

Tags: gsap

Looking at the bezier plugin, http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/BezierPlugin/

It doesn't make a lot of sense to me.
I couldn't translate my CSS cubic-bezier of cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1) to GSAP using that plugin.

How would you do that?

Cheers,
V.

Comment: See https://greensock.com/forums/topic/30663-which-gsap-ease-best-matches-csss-transition-timing-function-ease/ where I had a similar question and the GSAP guys gave me the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The administrator from GSAP has replied me.
They told me bezier plugin is for animating values along a bezier path.

I will have to resort to the predefined, power1, power2, power3, power4 etc built in easing.

Or pay to be a Greensock member and use the customease plugin
https://greensock.com/customease

---

Solution:
Some kind folks out there has made a plugin for the translation.
https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing

TweenLite.to("#yourElement", 1, {x:100, ease:new Ease(BezierEasing(0.7,0,0.3,1))});